# How to add C# code to a new Orchard CMS theme

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

### Introduce the Problem

I would like to implement the Orchard `IShapeTableProvider,` in order to add an alternate for the main `List` shape. I have done the following:

Download [Orchard.Source.1.8.zip](http://orchard.codeplex.com/releases/view/115750), build in VS 2013, and create a new theme via code generation:

```
  orchard.exe
  feature enable Orchard.CodeGeneration
  codegen theme My.FirstTheme
  theme enable My.FirstTheme
```

Add the following code to my theme in the Themes > My.FirstTheme > Code > ListShapeProvider.cs file.

```
namespace Themes.My.FirstTheme.Code
{
    using Orchard.Autoroute.Models;
    using Orchard.ContentManagement;
    using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors;
    public class ListShapeProvider : IShapeTableProvider
    {
        public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // * not hit
        }
    }
}
```

Clean and build the Orchard solution, then debug Orchard.Web. The debugger does not hit System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break().

### Search and Research

I have read [Orchard shapeshifting](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/01/10/orchard-shapeshifting.aspx) by Orchard's Benevolent Dictator.

Further, I have installed, built, and run the Contoso theme as an example implementation of `IShapeTableProvider`. The implementation of `IShapeTableProvider` is in the ContentShapeProvider.cs file. The Contoso theme also includes a Contoso.csproj file that has the ContentShapeProvider.cs file as a Compile Item.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="Code\ContentShapeProvider.cs" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

The new theme that I created does not have a .csproj file. I think the missing .csproj file explains why my ListShapeProvider.cs breakpoint is not executing.

Should I create a .csproj file for my theme? Is there another recommended way to include C# in the theme? For instance, should I use an App_Code folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Orchard.exe code generation, add `/CreateProject:true`. This will generate a .csproj file for you. E.g.

```
orchard.exe
feature enable Orchard.CodeGeneration
codegen theme My.FirstTheme /CreateProject:true
theme enable My.FirstTheme
```

Now when you add a ListShapeProvider.cs file, Visual Studio will automatically as the following entry to the My.FirstTheme.csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="ListShapeProvider.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `/IncludeInsolution:true` too in your `codegen theme My.FirstTheme /CreateProject:true`
It will add your theme project under the Themes top level folder.