# Orchard link to module not working

Tags: orchardcms-1.8

I'm following the tutorial for creating an orchard module here:
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Building-a-hello-world-module

At the end of the tutorial, after enabling and adding the link to the menu, I rebuild Orchard, fire it up, click the link to the module that I created but get nothing but a not found page:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is    
temporarily     
unavailable.

Requested URL      http://localhost:30321/MyModule
Physical Path      C:\Users\Rich\Documents\My Web Sites\Orchard.Web-   
                       Site\MyModule
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User             Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory           
C:\Users\Rich\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\ORCHARD.WEB-SITE
```

Any idea what is going on? I created the Routes.cs file - renamed everything accordingly to match the name of my module and as far as I can tell, have not missed anything.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, Running via VS and Orchard 1.8

Comment: Where you do get this Error msg from? Have a look in the Orchard Logs. There are under the App_Data folder. Also, your module seems to be off the Orchard.Web root when it should be under 'Modules'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in the comments, your module seems not to be under the 'Modules' folder...

This question posted is kind of the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616534/how-to-add-c-sharp-code-to-a-new-orchard-cms-theme/24217712#24217712)

Make sure you start always like this, so you can get all the references to the project properly set up:

```
orchard
feature enable Orchard.CodeGeneration
codegen module YouModuleName /CreateProject:true /IncludeInSolution:true
```

The last bit `/IncludeInSolution:true` will hook your project under the Modules top level folder too. 
I always try not to touch anything under Orchard.Web

Comment: Yeah, pretty similar to the problem I faced so this helped me. VS was launching the site under localhost\orchardSite\ ... So my module was expecting to be in localhost\mymodule. Once I changed the projectUrl to localhost:myport, all worked as expected. Thanks for pointing me in the right diretion.